# How to show and hide items in dynamic rows in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and I can't seem to find a way to do this appropriately.  I created a custom directive to Apply a function a pass in the row Index.  However, I can't seem to think of the way to show items in a row.  What would be the best way to do this?  I want to show specific and hide a target row via controller.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" data-index="{{$index}}">
   <div>other information</div>
   <div class="item hidden" ng-class="{hidden: hidden[{{$index}}]}">
         Item     
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Directive:**

```
 scope.$apply(function () {
     scope.$parent.showItem(index);
 });
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.teamDrop = function(index) {
    $scope.hidden[index] = false;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives to hide and show elements.

You can also use the `ng-if` directive to remove elements from the dom.

For your example I'd change your `ng-class` to an `ng-hide`

```
<div class="row" data-index="{{$index}}">
   <div>other information</div>
   <div class="item hidden" ng-hide="hidden[$index]">
         Item     
    </div>
</div>
```

You also don't need to use the {{}} syntax in the ng-class becausue it's already expecting an angular expression, that's for data binding.

Comment: I am currently using directives, but I am trying to figure out how I can target a specific row.

Comment: I assumed your array contains a list of booleans

Comment: Do i have to declare an array of booleans or can I use !! ?

Comment: You can use any expression there which returns a boolean. Expressions are evaluated against the scope, so if your scope has a function `shouldShow(index)` you can use the result of that method call or you can simply compare a scope property to a literal value `($index % 2) == 1`.